# Waiting for dynamically added images to load (cross-browser support)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I've got an overlay that's hidden on the page, when the user clicks a link some `<img>` tags get their src attribute populated, then using the load event on the `<img>` tags I determine when to make the overlay visible.

This works perfectly in Chrome however I've read that this isn't cross-browser supported and sure enough this only works the first time in Safari, trying to view the same content a second time causes the load event to never fire.

Is there another way around this that will work across browsers?

Comment: How have you registered with the image's load event?

Comment: Tried `.load()` as well as `.on('load')`. The jQuery docs page for `.load()` explains that it won't work cross browser. I've also tried [this plugin](https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages) which works in Safari but not IE 9.

Comment: If you're still having issues, perhaps there is a solution in CSS. Why do you need to wait for the image to load to display the overlay? Maybe you can post the code you tried as well?